# logit function in R

Tags: r, math

I read in the data set labeled Brass and I need to find the logit function log (p/1-p) for the 3 countries for each age and plot against brass standard.

```
dat <- structure(list(Age=c(1L,5L,10L,20L,30L),Brass_Standard=c(85,76.9,75,71.3,65.2),Sweden=c(98.7,98.4,98.2,97.9,97.4),Italy=c(84.8,73.9,72.1,69.9,64.1),Japan=c(96.4,95.2,94.7,93.8,91.7)),.Names=c("Age","Brass_Standard","Sweden","Italy","Japan"),class="data.frame",row.names=c("1","2","3","4","5"))

     Age   Brass_Standard  Sweden  Italy  Japan
1      1             85.0    98.7   84.8   96.4
2      5             76.9    98.4   73.9   95.2
3     10             75.0    98.2   72.1   94.7
4     20             71.3    97.9   69.9   93.8
5     30             65.2    97.4   64.1   91.7
```

I defined the logit in R as

```
logit<-function(x) log(x/(1-x))
```

but when I try to perform on the values for say Sweden, I get an error. Secondly,how do I plot the logit curve for the countries to compare them.

Comment: You have to change 85.0% into 0.85. Then you can apply your logit function. (Please consider editing your question, your data is difficult to read.)

Comment: @Marco is right about percentages vs proportions.  If you want you can use the built-in `plogis()` function instead of writing your own `logit()` function.

Comment: There is no vector type that supports digits followed by %-signs except `character` and it those were in a dataframe they would furthermore be entered by default as factor class. So any efforts to "fix" this dataframe should first look at its structure.

Answer (score 4):

Read data:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(
"Age Brass_Standard    Sweden  Italy   Japan
1   1   85.0   98.7   84.8   96.4
2   5   76.9   98.4   73.9   95.2
3   10  75.0   98.2   72.1   94.7
4   20  71.3   97.9   69.9   93.8
5   30  65.2   97.4   64.1   91.7
"))
```

Get packages:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
```

Rescale percentages to proportions:

```
dat[,-1] <- dat[,-1]/100
```

Reshape data:

```
mdat <- melt(dat,id.var="Age")
```

Plot all variables (including `Brass_Standard`) vs age, with y-axis transformed to a logit scale, with linear regression fits shown:

```
qplot(Age,value,data=mdat,colour=variable)+
    scale_y_continuous(trans=logit_trans())+
    geom_smooth(method="lm")+theme_bw()
ggsave("logitplot1.png")
```

[image]

Reshape data slightly differently:

```
mdat2 <- melt(dat,id.var=c("Age","Brass_Standard"))
```

Plot data vs. `Brass_Standard` rather than vs. `Age`: transform both x and y to logit scales, and add linear regression fits again.

```
qplot(Brass_Standard,value,data=mdat2,colour=variable)+
    scale_y_continuous(trans=logit_trans())+
    scale_x_continuous(trans=logit_trans())+
    geom_smooth(method="lm")+
    theme_bw()
ggsave("logitplot2.png")
```

[image]

If you need to get the coefficients of these fits I would suggest something like:

```
library(nlme)
pdat <- with(mdat2,data.frame(Age,variable,
                              logit_Brass_Standard=plogis(Brass_Standard),
                              logit_value=plogis(value)))

fit1 <- lmList(logit_Brass_Standard~logit_value|variable,data=pdat)
coef(fit1)
```

http://www.demog.berkeley.edu/~eddieh/toolbox.html#BrassMortality looks like it might be useful too.

(I hope I'm not doing your homework for you ...)